# Swift - Nested Enums default values

Tags: swift

I have an enum as follows

```
enum AccountForm: String {

    case Profile

    enum Content: String {
        case Feedback
        case Likes
    }

    enum Actions: String {
        case Redeem
        case Help
    }
}
```

This represents a form, where `profile` `content` and `actions` are sections and the cases are rows.

These resolve to strings and work as expected

`AccountForm.Profile.rawValue`  returns "Profile"

`AccountForm.Content.Feedback.rawValue`  returns "Feedback"

However, I'd like `AccountForm.Content.rawValue` to return "Content"

Is this possible? Or is there a better way besides enums to achieve this?

Comment: What are you using the string values for? It really looks like you actually don't want to use enums like this, I cannot know what structure would fit without knowing the use case though

Comment: @Kametrixom I'm creating constant strings to use as tags while creating a form. Profile, Content, Actions are sections and Feedback, Likes, etc are rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've got an answer to this by now but just in case you didn't try this:

```
enum AccountForm : String {
    case profile

    enum Content: String {
        static let rawValue = "Content"

        case feedback = "Feedback"
        case likes = "Likes"
    }

    enum Actions : String {
        static let rawValue = "Actions"

        case redeem = "Redeem"
        case help = "Help"
    }
}
```

Static properties on both the `Content` and `Actions` enumerations should achieve what you want.  A word of warning though.  By calling the properties `rawValue` you're obviously implying the returned values are raw values when technically they aren't.  If you can I'd think of a better name (maybe `sectionTitle`?).

Couple of other things to note.

First, you have to define the properties as `static` as it sounds like you want to call them on the enumeration *type* (e.g. `AccountForm.Content.rawValue`) rather than on an individual enumeration *case* (e.g. `AccountForm.Content.feedback.rawValue`). I'll leave you to decide whether that makes sense in your context.

Secondly, when Swift 3.0 arrives, the recommendation for enumeration cases is going to be that case labels follow a `lowerCamelCase` naming convention rather than the `UpperCamelCase` convention that was recommended in Swift 2.2.

I've followed the Swift 3.0 recommendation here but the result is that explicit raw-value assignments is needed as you won't be able to rely on using the implicit raw-value assignment mechanism assigning a string with an `UpperCamelCase` representation which is kind of annoying but those are the implications.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
enum Typo {
    case Bold
    case Normal
    case Italic
    case All
}
enum Format: CustomStringConvertible {
    case Header(Typo)
    case Text(Typo)
    var description:String {
        switch self {
        case .Header(let value) where value != .All:
            return "Header.\(value)"
        case .Header(let value) where value == .All:
            return "Header"
        case .Text(let value) where value == .All:
            return "Text"
        case .Text(let value) where value != .All:
            return "Text.\(value)"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}

let a:Format = .Header(.Bold)
let b:Format = .Text(.Italic)

Format.Header(.All)   // Header
Format.Text(.Bold)    // Text.Bold
Format.Text(.All)     // Text
```

Comment: @Eric D: are you sure?